Alpha blending two smokes and game world allows to see through smoke
We have a bug in Call of Duty 1 when two smokes are deployed and player's POV is facing bloomed smokes in straight line.
Then, player can see other players or objects which happen to be between those smokes.
The underlying engine used to render is the same as Quake III Arena.
Please see the below images examples:

From top:
View from top
Player's pov:
Player's pov

I think this is an issue with incorrect alpha blending between smoke TGA images and world.
smoke_grenade.shader file uses blendfunc blend which equals to gl_src_alpha gl_one_minus_src_alpha:
/////////////////////////////          smoke particle top         ///////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

smoke_grenade/smk_p_top_wht_a
{
    //sort additive
    sort nearest
    {
       map gfx/efx_assets/smoke/smk_p_top_wht_a.dds
       blendfunc blend
       rgbGen vertex
    }
}

smoke_grenade/smk_p_top_wht_b
{
    //sort additive
    sort nearest
    {
       map gfx/efx_assets/smoke/smk_p_top_wht_b.dds
       blendfunc blend
       rgbGen vertex
    }
}

smoke_grenade/smk_p_top_wht_c
{
    //sort additive
    sort nearest
    {
       map gfx/efx_assets/smoke/smk_p_top_wht_c.dds
       blendfunc blend
       rgbGen vertex
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////          smoke particle none        ///////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

smoke_grenade/smk_p_none_wht_a
{
    //sort additive
    sort nearest
    {
       map gfx/efx_assets/smoke/smk_p_none_wht_a.dds
       blendfunc blend
       rgbGen vertex
    }
}

smoke_grenade/smk_p_none_wht_b
{
    //sort additive
    sort nearest
    {
       map gfx/efx_assets/smoke/smk_p_none_wht_b.dds
       blendfunc blend
       rgbGen vertex
    }
}

smoke_grenade/smk_p_none_wht_c
{
    //sort additive
    sort nearest
    {
       map gfx/efx_assets/smoke/smk_p_none_wht_c.dds
       blendfunc blend
       rgbGen vertex
    }
}

Below is the example of one layer of smoke .efx file content that is run by FxRunner:
Particle
{
    name                1__smoke_linger

    life                2000

    cullrange           32000

    origin              12 0 21

    rotation            0 360

    rotationDelta           -15 15

    velocity            50 0 18

    gravity             8

    rgb
    {
        start           0.749 0.7529 0.6863
        end             0.7529 0.7529 0.7529
        flags           linear
    }

    size
    {
        start           50
        end             100
        flags           linear
    }

    shaders
    [
        smoke_grenade/smk_p_none_wht_a
    ]
}

Particle
{
    name                2__smoke_linger

    life                2300

    cullrange           32000

    origin              12 14 14

    rotation            0 360

    rotationDelta           -15 15

    velocity            35 4 7

    gravity             15

    rgb
    {
        start           0.749 0.7529 0.6863
        end             0.7529 0.7529 0.7529
        flags           linear
    }

    size
    {
        start           25
        end             150
        flags           linear
    }

    shaders
    [
        smoke_grenade/smk_p_none_wht_b
    ]
}

Particle
{
    name                3__smoke_linger

    life                1750

    cullrange           32000

    origin              12 21 0

    rotation            0 360

    rotationDelta           -15 15

    velocity            15 12 0

    gravity             25

    rgb
    {
        start           0.749 0.7529 0.6863
        end             0.7529 0.7529 0.7529
        flags           linear
    }

    size
    {
        start           35
        end             125
        flags           linear
    }

    shaders
    [
        smoke_grenade/smk_p_none_wht_c
    ]
}

Particle
{
    name                4__smoke_linger

    life                1500

    cullrange           32000

    origin              12 14 -14

    rotation            0 360

    rotationDelta           -15 15

    velocity            65 5 -8

    gravity             12

    rgb
    {
        start           0.749 0.7529 0.6863
        end             0.7529 0.7529 0.7529
        flags           linear
    }

    size
    {
        start           48
        end             140
        flags           linear
    }

    shaders
    [
        smoke_grenade/smk_p_none_wht_a
    ]
}

Particle
{
    name                5__smoke_linger

    life                2400

    cullrange           32000

    origin              12 0 -21

    rotation            0 360

    rotationDelta           -15 15

    velocity            80 0 -12

    gravity             6

    rgb
    {
        start           0.749 0.7529 0.6863
        end             0.7529 0.7529 0.7529
        flags           linear
    }

    size
    {
        start           25
        end             120
        flags           linear
    }

    shaders
    [
        smoke_grenade/smk_p_none_wht_b
    ]
}

Particle
{
    name                6__smoke_linger

    life                2200

    cullrange           32000

    origin              12 -14 -14

    rotation            0 360

    rotationDelta           -15 15

    velocity            35 -6 -7

    gravity             8

    rgb
    {
        start           0.749 0.7529 0.6863
        end             0.7529 0.7529 0.7529
        flags           linear
    }

    size
    {
        start           40
        end             135
        flags           linear
    }

    shaders
    [
        smoke_grenade/smk_p_none_wht_c
    ]
}

Particle
{
    name                7__smoke_linger

    life                2400

    cullrange           32000

    origin              12 -21 0

    rotation            0 360

    rotationDelta           -15 15

    velocity            25 -15 2

    gravity             22

    rgb
    {
        start           0.749 0.7529 0.6863
        end             0.7529 0.7529 0.7529
        flags           linear
    }

    size
    {
        start           30
        end             210
        flags           linear
    }

    shaders
    [
        smoke_grenade/smk_p_none_wht_a
    ]
}

Particle
{
    name                8__smoke_linger

    life                1600

    cullrange           32000

    origin              12 -14 14

    rotation            0 360

    rotationDelta           -15 15

    velocity            65 7 7

    gravity             14

    rgb
    {
        start           0.749 0.7529 0.6863
        end             0.7529 0.7529 0.7529
        flags           linear
    }

    size
    {
        start           35
        end             125
        flags           linear
    }

    shaders
    [
        smoke_grenade/smk_p_none_wht_b
    ]
}

Is there a simple way via modding or editing the shader or efx or maybe .dds file to make the closest/foreground smoke to be rendered solid and prevent see-through smoke players or objects when another smoke is thrown (rendered) behind at the same time?
